# Discrete Time Logistic

Tags: stata, discrete-time

I'm trying to use panel survey data to determine married event in life using discrete logistic regression. However, some observations enter the survey not the same time as other i.e. some enter in 1990 and others in 1995. Does everyone think it's fine if I use the duration that they enter the survey as t or period variable?

Any comments will be much appreciated
Thank you so much!

Comment: seems fine. presumably you would add the entrance time as an additional ?categorical variable (can even interact with t)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. You mean I should create another variable as an entrance time, right?

Comment: Yes create an extra variable

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!